# unable to return the string from spring controller and show on the webpage

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am using springmvc and angularjs to read the data and show on the webpage.
For reading the data from URL i have used JSoup API.

Facing errors while dispalying the content read from the URL back to the webpage.Any suggestions would be helpful.

code:

html:

```
<div ng-controller="readContentController">
                                <div>
                                    {{content}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

js code:

```
//controller

myApp.controller('readContentController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $sce, ReportService, $window) {
    $scope.content = {};
    MyService.getDataFromURL().then(
        function (response) {
            console.log("response :" + response);
            $scope.content = response;
             },
        function (errResponse) {
           $rootScope.showError("error :" + errResponse);
        });
});
//service call
myServiceFactory.getDataFromURL = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/getHTMLDataFromURL')
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching data' + errResponse);
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getHTMLDataFromURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody String getHtmlStrigContent() throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://xyz.abc.com/myFile.pdf").get();
        String htmlString = doc.toString();
        System.out.println("asD" + htmlString);
        return htmlString;
}
```

Error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ec (angular.min.js:16)
    at ic (angular.min.js:93)
    at angular.min.js:93
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at od (angular.min.js:93)
    at f (angular.min.js:95)
    at angular.min.js:132
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:146)
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:143)
(anonymous) @ angular.min.js:119
myService.js:158 Error while fetching dataSyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I trying to read the content from another webpage and display in our application webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Angular thinks the response should be JSON and not HTML. In your `@RequestMapping` annotation, try adding `produces="text/plain"` or `produces="text/html"`.

However, you also have another problem: by default Angular will not display the contents of a variable as HTML due to the obvious security problems. You will need to explicitly tell Angular that you trust the contents before you can use it in this way. [See the documentation for $sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) for an example on how to do this.

Comment: It is working but i want to show the output of html , i mean i'm reading the html content from URL,when i open it in browser it will display the webpage(the same page which we see when we hit the URL). Currently it is displaying as String, can i show the response as webpage instead of string representation of the html. Any advice would be helpful.thanks.

Comment: @sss: See my second paragraph. :)

Comment: @sss: Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like, js is trying to parse an HTML response in JSON format.

From AngularJS $http [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

The default header for all requests, is

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common (headers that are common for all requests):
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
```

The Default transformation is

```
If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.
```

You can override the default with having the Content-Type Header set in your request.

```
var req = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: '/getHTMLDataFromURL',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
   'Accept': 'text/plain'
 }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Comment: It is displaying same error when removed response.data and tried with response

Comment: Editing my response, from, AngularJS $http documentation,  the default header for Content Type is :$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common (headers that are common for all requests):
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*, you will have to change it to accept text only.

Comment: Thanks, it is show as string on the webpage now. How can i show the returned response as a webpage(as the response is an html content).

Comment: use something like $( ".inner" ).append("<html><body>hello</body></html>" , see append() function of jquery

Comment: @abstractnature: Angular does not have a complete jquery implementation, and I don't think `append` is supported (though I could be wrong). In any case the $sce service is the preferred way to handle this in Angular.